# How can plot descending bar and ascending curve which are related to each other by connecting them in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was wondering if it is possible to plot bars in descending order and another ascending curve which are related to each other and should be somehow connected. I tried some codes, but I just can plot bars and curve individually but I couldn't plot **dashed curve** such a way that it can pass through the center of bins like the following the target result and i also coulddn't figure out how I can change the color of the smallest bar orange:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

objects = ('ResNet', 'GoogleNet', 'VGG', 'ZFNet', 'AlexNet', 'b', 'c')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [3.57,6.7,7.3,11.7,16.4,25.8,28.2]
your_y_coordinates=[152,22,19,8,8,1,1]
plt.plot(y_pos, your_y_coordinates, '--', label='layers',color='orange',linewidth=1.5 , marker='o',)
plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
y_pos, objects = plt.xticks()

plt.ylabel('Error rate [%]')
plt.title('ImageNet Classification top-5 error %')
for i, v in enumerate(performance):
    plt.text(y_pos[i] - 0.25, v + 0.01, str(v))

x_position = [1,6,2,7,4,5]
y_position = [8,4,7,7,2,4]

plt.plot(x_position, y_position, 'rx')

labels = ['hi'.format(i) for i in range(len(x_position))]
for label, x, y in zip(labels, x_position, y_position):
    plt.annotate(label, xy=(x, y), xytext=(2, 2), bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.2', fc='yellow', alpha=0.3))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Comment: `plt.plot(y_pos, your_y_coordinates)`?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I tried [but](https://i.imgur.com/EpByBDv.png) I can't make the triangles in center of bars and I have no clue how I can color smallest bar orange and also lift a bit values on the top side of the bars!

Comment: Check how other people get their markers into the plot, how they colorize bars and how they annotate them.

Comment: also use `zorder` to bring the plot to the front of bar.

Comment: @mamun that's right I already dealt with that issue.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I did some progress but how I can annotate for each bar and colorize the smallest bar?